DMGs on SMB share are read-only after some time
I have a SMB share on a Synology NAS, where I have full r/w permissions. I created some encrypted DMGs (also r/w) every now and then. After a while they turn to read-only, even if they are empty. This seems to happen since Sonoma. Another Apple bug??? I didn't change anything on the NAS. I'm completely at loss where to search for the cause. I still can create anything in the same folder, files, DMGs, other folders etc. Everything stays r/w. Only DMGs change.
Edit 1: They remain read-only, regardless of what I'm doing and which Mac i'm using. I created them via Disk Utility – new empty HFS+ disk image, 2 GB, 256 bit encryption, no or GUID partition, expanding. They can contain anything, mainly TXT and JPGs. Synology is on DSM 7.1.1. This happens regardless of changing anything of its contents.
Edit 2: As requested, the following two commands output before (r/w)…
❯ hdiutil imageinfo /Volumes/share/test.sparseimage | grep Format
Enter password:
Format: SPRS
Format Description: growing

❯ ls -leO@ /Volumes/share/test.sparseimage
-rwx------  1 mk  staff  - 127004160  2 Sep 08:14 /Volumes/share/test.sparseimage

and after (ro)…
❯ hdiutil imageinfo /Volumes/share/test.sparseimage | grep Format
Enter password:
Format: SPRS
Format Description: growing
❯ ls -leO@ /Volumes/share/test.sparseimage
-rwx------@ 1 mk  staff  - 127004160 25 Apr 21:14 /Volumes/share/test.sparseimage
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS          16


Do they remain read-only, or are you able to write to them again after a time or after doing something like disconnecting and reconnecting, or restarting your computer, or something else? What changes are you making to these DMGs? What do they contain? What version of the Synology software are you running? What are the details of your network?

There are a plethora of different disk image types that all use the .dmg filename extension. Please be more specific about how you're creating these images and what type you're creating, and if the type is getting changed. Look at the man page for hdiutil.

Thanks. See my edits.

Can you edit your Question to add the output of hdiutil imageinfo filename.dmg | grep Format and ls -leO@ filename.dmg from both when the disk image is still read/write, and after it goes read-only? (BTW that's a capital letter O, not a zero, in the options to ls). I'm trying to understand if it's actually being turned into a read-only format internal to the disk image structure, or if it's just the .dmg file on disk that's being made read-only via filesystem permissions.

See my "Edit 2".
